# mongodb select from different databases

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have about 200 mongodb databases.
Every database has a collection called 'Group' and in this collection there is a field called 'meldingId'.

Is it possible to make a one mongodb query which find all values in the different databases.

(I managed to select the databases bij looping through the databases by selectDB($database_name))

Comment: As at MongoDB 3.0 you can't create single queries that span multiple collections or databases. You can write a function to iterate databases/collections but that will still result in a query per namespace (which sounds like what you may already be doing).

Answer (score 12):

In Mongo shell, this can be done by using **[`db.getSiblingDB()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/)** method to switch to admin database and get a list of the 200 databases by running the admin command `db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 })`. Iterate over the list of databases and use **[`db.getSiblingDB()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/)** again to switch between databases, query the `Group` collection for the `meldingId` values. Something like this:

```js
// Switch to admin database and get list of databases.
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases;

// Iterate through each database.
dbs.forEach(function(database) {
    db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);

    // Get the Group collection
    collection = db.getCollection("Group");

    // Iterate through all documents in collection.
    /*
        collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {

            // Print the meldingId field.
            print(doc.meldingId);
        });
    */

    var meldingIds = collection.distinct('meldingId');
    print(meldingIds);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB query multiple databases at once
The same as @chridam answer, but with small improvement to generalize the db name, and as a one-liner:
This command will count all the collection with the same name in different databases:

```
collectionName = "sites"; db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases; dbs.forEach(function(database) { db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name); collection = db.getCollection(collectionName); print(collection + " count: " + collection.count())})
```

And the results are:

```
db_0.sites count: 0
db_1.sites count: 0
db_2.sites count: 3
db_3.sites count: 4
```

You can use it for different purposes just change the collectionName value, or the query in the forEach function.