# Is It Possible to Join Two different databases collections in Mongodb with the common field

Tags: mongodb

i have done with in the same database, Can someone help i need to join different database collection and push it to elasticsearch to visualize in kibana

Comment: Please provide minimal code of what you have already tried, examples of your collections data structures and an example of the data structure of end result

Comment: i have two databases user database and product database. product database will have a collection called smartbulb in that customerid will be there,and user database will have registered users collection in that customerid will also be there, so i want to join both of that using the common field customer id.    tried 1: same like in RDBMS databasename.collectionname.fieldname and lookup with the customer field.it didnt work obviously. and now following this link from stackoverflow to join:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003922/mongodb-select-from-different-databases